# SDK versions in aapt command output

Tags: applications

**Update:**
- My first question was answered [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html#appversioning), thanks to Andrew's comment.
Quote:

> If you specify API level requirements directly in your app's manifest
>   file, the corresponding settings in the build files will override the
>   settings in the manifest file

I was able to retrieve `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` by `aapt list`. In this example, after converting from hex, they are 16 and 26, respectively. I am aware of `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` which are usually declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. However, I have decompiled the APK file using `apktool` and checked the `AndroidManifest.xml` file but  could not see any declaration of `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` either.

Was that because `apktool` did not decompile everything or these elements can be declared in other place of the APK instead of the manifest file? **(my first question)**

```
aapt list -a  0348e77633b7831d1d56cd2f45023bd4.apk | grep -i sdkversion
A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1a
...
```

By issuing `aapt d badging`. There are `sdkVersion:'9'` and `targetSdkVersion:'26'` in the output.

```
aapt d badging 0348e77633b7831d1d56cd2f45023bd4.apk |head
package: name='com.theborneopost.mobileapp' versionCode='60001' versionName='6.0.1' platformBuildVersionName=''
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'26'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
...
```

So, are there any differences between `targetSdkVersion` in `aapt` and `apktool` output? Assume that `targetSdkVersion` is available in `AndroidManifest.xml` **(my second question)**

What is `sdkVersion` in `aapt d badging` output? **(my third question)**

**Disclaimer**: due to limitations, I could not add appropriate tags like `aapt` or `sdkversion` to the post.

Comment: Some insights on this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002844/2821954)

Comment: Andrew, that definitely helps. I will modify my question based on it